# How do I make and code a splash screen for an app in NativeScript (Angular)?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to put an Splash Screen on the app that Im developing on NativeScript with angular, the problem is that I don't know how to create it and then implement it on the app.

What I want is just a screen that shows when I hopen the app and then just goes into a login screen (already have the login screen).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [nativescript-splashscreen](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-splashscreen/) if you like to customise splash screen with cool animations & components.

**Edit:** If you are looking for a loading indicator to let user know you are processing something or waiting for a network call, you could use [nativescript-loading-indicator](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-loading-indicator) Or even host your own dialog if you need something more customized.

Answer (score -1):

You can use loader kind of mechanism if you want to just put some content for sometime you can add content on loader screen and it will be shows for defined time

you can use **ngx-ui-loader** npm package for this

else you can create new component and make it as dailog window that will open on login page loading and than it will be closed by click or timeout. you can use different NPM library for this.

This both approach might solve your splash screen problem.

Comment: `ngx-ui-loader` or any package that uses HTML dom / any broswer specific features are not compatible with NativeScript.